# Getting email address displayed on Windows 10 login screen even for domain accounts

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, windows-domain, login-screen

On someone's Windows 8 computer, several years ago, I saw his **email address displayed on login screen**. I happened to find the computer in the lecture hall I was just leaving and this struck me as a great way to contact the owner. I wanted that on my computer, too. My email address is public in many places and tied to my name, anyway, and I am able to filter my mail so that some more unsolicited messages are no problem.

Yesterday, I installed **Windows 10 Anniversary Update** and I was looking forward to being able to display my email address on login screen. I enabled the display of personal info on the login screen (**Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options > Privacy**) and logged off in order to see the result.

No change. :-( Still just my name and `DOMAIN\username` underneath. **My account is a domain account with associated Microsoft account and e-mail account** (Settings > Accounts > Your email and accounts). I tried the same with my local account with administrative privileges; adding email account did not change anything (still displayed nothing under the account name), but when I chose "Sign in with a Microsoft account instead", the account name changed to my real name and the email address displayed on login screen.

**How can I display my email address on Windows 10 login screen even for my domain account?**

Comment: You can't.  The feature is connect to accounts linked to MS accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working work-around I know about uses Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), which needs administrator privileges*.

Under `Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`, set:

- Interactive Logon: Message title for users attempting to log on
- Interactive Logon: Message text for users attempting to log on

It will be displayed to the first user attempting to log in after Windows start, just after the lock screen an just before the login screen.

I chose to use my email address as the title and added this text:

> In case you have found this computer, return it to its owner, [my name], who can be contacted on the email address above.

There seems to be a way to [achieve the same using Registry Editor](https://www.maketecheasier.com/custom-message-windows-10-login/) (`regedit.exe`). This might be useful if you want to create a `.reg` file to do the same with multiple computers.

Also, [the same procedure is reported to be working for Windows 7 and 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/displaying-customized-start-message-windows-8).

<sub>* Also, Local Group Policy Editor is not available in Home edition, but [Home edition does not support domain accounts](https://superuser.com/q/516334/269404), anyway. In case the support can be hacked in somehow, you can [try adding Group Policy Editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqk3vtTYfzY) (untested).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature 'Display Password Hint' where you can enter any text you like.

Its intention is to give you a hint for remembering your password, but of course you can use it for anything, like putting your email address there.

Comment: This would not be automatically updated when I change email association to the account. Still, it's better than nothing. But how can I use this feature? When changing the password (Ctrl + Alt + Del is the only option for domain accounts I know), there is no field for the hint to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Your account is a domain account.  Under the current system, Your account would need to be logging in with the microsoft account and you're not.